# CakePHP: Joined Table Data Not Displaying in View

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have two Models linked in a hasMany/belongsTo relationship. Here is the hasMany definition:

```
//Table hr_emp_ids. Each employee can have many HR cases.
public $hasMany = array(
    'HrCase' => array(
        'className' => 'HrCase',
        'foreignKey' => 'emp_user_id'
        )
    );
```

And here is the belongsTo definition:

```
//Table hr_cases. Each HR case is owned by an employee.
public $belongsTo = array(
    'HrEmpId' => array(
        'className'=> 'HrEmpId',
        'foreignKey' => 'emp_user_id'
    );
```

The Controller for my view is dead simple:

```
public function view($id = null) {      
    $this->HrCase->id = $id;
    if (!$this->HrCase->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Case ID'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('HrCase.' . $this->HrCase->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('case', $this->HrCase->find('first', $options));
}
```

All I'm trying to do is display the hire_date and ssn from the hr_emp_ids table based on hr_cases.emp_user_id = hr_emp_ids = emp_user_id. Here is the View code:

```
<tr>
<td><strong>Employee: </strong><br><?php echo h($case['HrCase']['full_name']); ?></td>
<td><strong>Date of Hire: </strong><br><?php echo h($case['HrEmpId']['hire_date']); ?></td>
<td><strong>SSN: </strong><br><?php echo h($case['HrEmpId']['ssn']); ?></td>
```

Table structures:

```
desc hr_emp_ids;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| hire_date   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ssn         | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| emp_user_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc hr_cases; (truncated)
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| emp_user_id        | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

Nothing from the HrEmpId model will display. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've made associations like this dozens of times with no trouble. What might I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any immediate reason why the associated data isn't showing.  Your find code here

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('HrCase.' . $this->HrCase->primaryKey => $id));
$this->set('case', $this->HrCase->find('first', $options));
```

looks like it could be simplified by using `getById()`, because the only condition in `$options` is checking the `$id`.  It's worth adding the `Containable Behavior` to the HrCase model and then setting the second argument of `getById()` to true.  This should allow you to specify exactly what associated data is returned.

Edit:

In the HrCase model you are setting up a `$belongsTo` relationship with the foreign key `emp_user_id`, but this is not the primary key in `hr_emp_ids`.
This is why the associated data isn't being returned.  You need to set up something like this:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'HrEmpId' => array(
        'foreignKey' => false,
         'conditions' => array(
             'HrEmpId.emp_user_id = HrCase.emp_user_id'
         ),
    )
);
```

see this for more info [How to associate model in CakePHP by fields not named by convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911052/how-to-associate-model-in-cakephp-by-fields-not-named-by-convention)

Comment: Good advice on using findById(). Also added Containable behavior to relevant models. Controller statement now looks like this: `$options = array($this->HrCase->findById($id), 'contain' => array('HrEmpId'));` Unfortunately, when I debug HrEmpId, the array is empty. Still stumped!

Comment: Which version of cake are you using?

Comment: We are on version 2.0.5.

Comment: I just made an edit to my answer.  Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner. Thanks. And I didn't realize until just now that I answered my own question above the View code! Hiding in plain sight.